# Is it possible to add the functionality of xwheel_zoom using slider widget on bokeh?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, bokeh

I basically want the functionality of xwheel_zoom tool in a slider. I know that we can change the values of the plot itself using slider widget with a callback function. But is it possible to have the functionality of xwheel_zoom in a slider.  I am developing the app using python flask and rendering html files.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0`, the built-in `Slider` widget does not support that interaction. Your options are:

- Request that this be added as a new feature by [making an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues). I can't speculate when the core time might be able to prioritize such a request, however.
- Create a [custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) that wraps some other JS slider widget that does support scroll interactions. This is not trivial, however, there is a complete ["Adding a Custom Widget"](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/widget.html) example that might get you started.